# chrome.tab.onactivated

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Can someone please show me how to use the `chrome.tabs.onActivated`.

I would like to refresh the tab that is clicked/activated if the url equals: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

Or if this is the wrong method please tell me what to use.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, be sure to put "tabs" permission in your `manifest.json` file. Then, use `chrome.tabs.onActivated` in your background page script. Each time this event will be called you will get `activeInfo` object containing currently active tab ID. Having this ID you can [fetch the tab](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-get) and see what URL is it set to. When you are certain that this is a tab you are looking for (URL matches) you can [reload it](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-reload).

Comment: Based on what you said and the links you gave i managed to get want i wanted.

js:

        chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(
     function(info) {
     
      chrome.tabs.get(info.tabId, function(tab) {
       
        if (tab.url == "www.example.com") {
         chrome.tabs.reload();
         }
      });
     });

thank you :D