# Is there an event fired in Chrome when the user selects a different tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to detect in my background page if the selected tab of chrome changes. For example if the user is on www.google.com in one tab and he changes to www.yahoo.com in another tab what is the best way of detecting

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active but that is more for a webpage

Comment: For a chrome extension check out `onActivated `https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onActivated

Comment: If this is for a Google Chrome Extension check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558528/chrome-tab-onactivated

Comment: Hi Dean. That seems to be exactly what I am looking for. For some strange reason I did not notice it when browsing the api.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my own question here. Within the chrome API the chrome.tabs.onActivated event is the exact event that I want to use. Thank you Jeff for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

The `blur` event is fired on the window, but not only for tab changes.

It is fired when the window loses its focus (*alt-tab to another app, click on the desktop etc*)..

So something like

```
window.addEventListener('blur', function(e){
    // just lost focus
}, false);
```