# Chrome extension get url of newly selected tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, event-listener

I have an extension which detects every time a webpage is changed using the chrome.tabs.onUpdated event listener. The code within this event listener performs certain tasks depending on the page URL. I also want to perform these tasks when switching from one tab to another, but this doesnt fire the chrome.tabs.onUpdated event listener, so instead im listening for the tab change using chrome.tabs.onActivated.

The problem is using chrome.tabs.onActivated does not give me the URL of the tab i have just switched to, which i need. Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [chrome.tab.onactivated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558528/chrome-tab-onactivated)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## You have 2 choices here:

---

1. ### Using two events (Not as good):

   ***IN ADDITION*** to the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` event that you're *ALREADY* using for your other functionality (you describe above), you could ALSO use **`chrome.tabs.get`** method to grab the `tabId` from the **`onActivated`**'s event object, then pass to a function.  But, IMHO option 2 is a better one for you in this case:

   ```
       chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
         //... whatever other stuff you were doing anyway
       });

       chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(evt){ 
         chrome.tabs.get(evt.tabId, function(tab){ 
           alert(tab.url);  //the URL you asked for in *THIS QUESTION*
         }); 
       });
   ```
2. ### Use only the **`onUpdated`** event once (better):

   Do both your other stuff and what you're looking for in your question in the same event:

   ```
       chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
         //... whatever other stuff you were doing anyway
         chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
           alert(tab.url);  //the URL you asked for in *THIS QUESTION*
         });
       });
   ```

.

## Of course, don't forget:

---

your `manifest.json` file should have the "**tabs** permission":

> ```
>   {
>     "name": "My extension",
>     ...
>     "permissions": [
>       "tabs"
>     ],
>     ...
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea in using chrome.tabs.onActivated.  When you get the event for onActivated, you should also get the activeInfo object, which should include the tab id.  With this, you can then do chrome.tabs.get(), passing in that tab id, and the tab object passed to the callback of chrome.tabs.get() should include the URL (though note you will need the "tabs" permission in your manifest to get the URL).